# Understanding Perl packages namespacing

Tags: perl, package, initialization

Consider this script (boiled down from the much larger one I have):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package help {
    my %HELPTEXT;
    $HELPTEXT{ "topic" } = "Some help\n";

    sub get_help( $ ) {
        print $HELPTEXT{ $_[0] };
    }
}

package main {
    sub main() {
        help::get_help( "topic" );
    }
}

main();
```

This works, prints `Some help`.

Now, I would like to place the initialization (`$HELPTEXT{ "topic" } = "Some help\n";` and others like it) at the end of the script -- while retaining `package help` and its code where it is.

However, this doesn't work:

```
# ...
main();

package help {
    $HELPTEXT{ "topic" } = "Some help";
}
```

Error message: `Global symbol "%HELPTEXT" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %HELPTEXT"?)`

This does not work either:

```
main();

$help::HELPTEXT{ "topic" } = "Some help\n";
```

Error message: `Name "help::HELPTEXT" only used once` / `Use of uninitialized value in print`.

Apparently my understanding of Perl packages and their namespacing is lacking.

**Can I have a variable in a mid-file package namespace, and still initialize it at end-of-file?**

**Added:** I figured out that the declaration issue can be resolved via `our`:

```
# ...
main();

package help {
    our %HELPTEXT;
    $HELPTEXT{ "topic" } = "Some help\n";
}
```

From perldoc:

> "our" makes a lexical alias to a package (i.e. global) variable of the same name in the current package for use within the current lexical scope.

However, this still gives an error: `Use of uninitialized value in print`. Even if I wrap the initialization in an `INIT {}` block.

I'd like to not only have a solution for this, but *understand* why this isn't working as I expected. Coding by guessing feels bad...

Comment: Where did `my %HELPTEXT;` go?

Comment: A variable declared with `my` goes out of scope outside of the block it was declared.

Comment: @choroba He is using two `package help` blocks... apparently you can do that, according to perldoc. It confused me too.

Comment: @TLP, yeah, no problem having separate pieces of code using the same package. The code before `package help { }` and after would be another example.

Comment: If you put the `main()` function call after the last package declaration, it works as intended. It appears to execute the code in the order it appears, which is not all that strange if you think about it. If I write `my $foo; print $foo; $foo = 'abc';` then it will not print `abc`, and we would not expect it to either.

Comment: You can get around the order of execution by placing the initializations inside a sub, and calling that sub where you need the initialization. I.e. putting `sub init_help { $HELPTEXT{foo} = "bar"; }`  at the end of your file, and calling it `init_help()` at the top, before the sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to understand here, and I write quite a bit more about this in [Learning Perl](https://www.learningperl.com). Most of this is realizing that lexical and package variables are two different systems. Anything that is lexical doesn't care what the default package is.

Here's your example with the `strict` failure:

```
use v5.12;
use strict;

package help {
    $HELPTEXT{ "topic" } = "Some help";
}
```

The `use strict` applies to whatever scope you employ it (file or block). In that scope, you have to either declare your variables on first use or use the full package specification. Since you do neither of those, you get the error. Changing the package doesn't turn it off.

The `package` declaration merely changes the default package name. With the block form, it only changes the default package in that block. Anything lexical doesn't care, including lexical variables. This `$foo` doesn't care what the default package is because it's not a package variable. It lasts until the scope (block or file) ends no matter what the default package is:

```
use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;

package help;

my $foo = 'bar';

package main;

say $foo;  # outputs bar
```

Using `our` instead has a curious effect when you combine packages in the same scope. You get a lexical variable with that name that is available anywhere in the scope and you get a package variable with that name (available anywhere in the program). They use the same data, so changing either changes the data and both versions show that:

```
use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;

package help;
our $foo = 'bar';

package main;

say $foo;        # bar
say $help::foo;  # bar

$help::foo = 'baz';

say $foo;        # baz
say $help::foo;  # baz
```

This doesn't work in the `package BLOCK` form because the `our` limits the lexical alias to that block, even though the package version is still there (and not limited to the block):

```
use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;

package help {
    our $foo = 'bar';
}

say $help::foo;  # bar
```

You could specify the full package specification, in which case `strict` no longer cares:

```
use v5.12;
use strict;

package help {
    $help::HELPTEXT{ "topic" } = "Some help";
}
```

Or, `use vars`:

```
use v5.12;
use strict;

package help {
    use vars qw(%HELPTEXT);
    $HELPTEXT{ "topic" } = "Some help";
}
```

You wanted some `help` package stuff at the top, then some more `help` package stuff at the bottom. Since the `package` just changes the default package, you can use it again. That is, you aren't limited to using it once and you aren't forced to put everything inside the first `help` block:

```
use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;

package help {
    use vars qw(%HELPTEXT);

    sub help { $HELPTEXT{$_[0]} }
}

say "TOPIC: " . help::help("topic");

package help {
    use vars qw(%HELPTEXT);

    $HELPTEXT{ "topic" } = "Some help";
}
```

This doesn't work because these are all run time statements. Perl compiles all of this, but it's then going to execute the statements in order. That means that the `$HELPTEXT{ "topic" } = "Some help";` doesn't run until the very end, after you try to use it.

A `BEGIN` solves that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;

package help {
    use vars qw(%HELPTEXT);

    sub help { $HELPTEXT{$_[0]} }
}

say "TOPIC: " . help::help("topic");

BEGIN {
    package help {
        use vars qw(%HELPTEXT);

        $HELPTEXT{ "topic" } = "Some help";
    }
}
```

When Perl compiles this, it reaches the BEGIN block and compiles it, but then runs its block immediately. The package variable for `%HELPTEXT` is setup and available anywhere in the program. By the time the top `package help {}` is run, that hash is already set up. It might be easier to see with some messages thrown in:

```
use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;

package help {
    use vars qw(%HELPTEXT);
    say "Setting up rest of help";

    sub help { $HELPTEXT{$_[0]} }
}

say "TOPIC: " . help::help("topic");

BEGIN {
    package help {
        use vars qw(%HELPTEXT);
        say "Setting up messages";
        $HELPTEXT{ "topic" } = "Some help";
    }
}
```

The output shows the order. The `BEGIN` runs first, then the top pf the script, and then the middle:

```
Setting up messages
Setting up rest of help
TOPIC: Some help
```

But, if you had a lexical variable instead, something different happens. The package variable is there, but the lexical version masks it while it is in scope:

```
use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;

$help::foo = 'quux';
say "Before: $help::foo";

package help {
    my $foo = 'bar';
    say "Inside: $foo";
}

say "After: $help::foo";
```

The output shows that:

Before: quux
Inside: bar
After: quux

But, remember the lexical masking is only inside the block. If you call out to something not in that scope,

```
use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;

$help::foo = 'quux';
say "Before: $help::foo";

package help {
    my $foo = 'bar';
    say "Inside: $foo";
    main::show_foo();
}

say "After: $help::foo";

sub show_foo { say "show_foo: $help::foo" }
```

The output shows that even when called inside the block, `show_foo` uses the package version despite it that subroutine being in a different package:

```
Before: quux
Inside: bar
show_foo: quux
After: quux
```

Thus, the trick is to know if your variable is lexical (affected by scope) or package.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for helping me understand.

Answer (score 1):

`INIT` does work (though `BEGIN` is more common).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package help {
    our %HELPTEXT;
    $HELPTEXT{ "topic" } = "Some help\n";

    sub get_help( $ ) {
        print $HELPTEXT{ $_[0] };
    }
}

package main {
    sub main() {
        help::get_help( "topic" );
    }
}

main::main();

INIT {
    package help;
    our %HELPTEXT;
    $HELPTEXT{ "topic" } = "Some help\n";
}
```

```
$ perl a.pl
Some help
```

I think you still had `my %HELPTEXT;` in the first block?

---

Instead of using `our` twice, you could use

```perl
use vars qw( %HELPTEXT );
```

In any case, what you are doing is a mess.

Comment: "What you are doing is a mess." -- In this sandbox, yes. In a script of several thousand lines, having the helptexts at the end instead of the middle of the code is just as helpful as keeping thinks like help, localization, etc. in individual packages... thanks for setting me back on track.

Comment: You could still have the `main::main()` right after. Or the text could be in a config file. Or in the DATA section. And that's not even getting into the multiple packages in the same file

Comment: You really want all of that to be configuration so normal people can update messages without touching code. You're doing a lot of work to re-invent a lot of stuff that people have been doing for decades. Survey the practices for other things that people do for the same task.

Comment: @briandfoy: Can you trust me that I don't do this willy-nilly? I already have everything in place (and tested) to load English-to-<locale> mappings from config file, but the script has to work without those config files, i.e. I need the English fallback texts in the script itself. I *know* about Locale::Maketext. Actually that is where I took my inspiration from. (That, and AmigaOS catalog files...) Some targets for this have rather crippled Perl support, and I want to have this working without requiring the user to set anything up.

Comment: @DevSolar - I don't know you, and I don't know all of the other people who will read this. If you want people to understand what you are doing and what model you are following, add that context to your question.

Comment: @briandfoy: What does it matter? The issue at hand was one of better understanding Perl namespaces, not one of "how to do help texts"; that was just the example (which I shoud probably have left out of the question so we would not have this conversation). I don't want to disclose my project at this point.

Comment: @DevSolar - yes, it matters. People read stuff on StackOverflow and then copy it. If someone doesn't add the caveats, those people don't know them. Remember, stackoverflow is more a service for people who later read answers than the people asking the original question.

Comment: @briandfoy: And you really think adding *more* information about my specific context would make this Q/A more *generally* useful?

I am afraid you're doing a bit too much trailing `unless` here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have any problem with package namespaces.  You seem to be using them correctly.  You're real issue seems to be variable scoping and order of execution.

Remember that Perl goes in two steps, compilation and execution.  On the first pass compile time actions happen which include legalizing symbols and creating the basic flow.  However none of those now legal variables are populated until runtime.  Variables defined at the end of the script aren't filled until runtime reaches them.  You can make it happen "right now" with `INIT` or `BEGIN` blocks as you found out.

You have two main options.  The first and more elegant IMO is to have a subroutine that both populates and returns the help text that you place at the end but call from wherever.  This uses the `state` keyword which is awesome because it let's you declare data right where it's used.  The one caveat is that it must be a scalar.  `state` declarations are only executed *once* at runtime (when you call the sub).

```perl
## the top

## thousands of lines of code

## the bottom

package help {
    sub get_help( $ ) {
        use feature qw/state/;
        state $HELPTEXT = { topic1 => "You need more help", topic2 => "RTFM", };
        print $HELPTEXT->{ $_[0] };
    }
}

## Or
sub help::get_help( $ ) { ...
```

The other option is to put a BEGIN block at the bottom that will populate to data.

```perl
## the top

package help {
    sub get_help( $ ) {
        our %HELPTEXT;
        print $HELPTEXT{ $_[0] };
    }
}

## thousands of lines of code

## the bottom

package help {
    BEGIN {
        our %HELPTEXT = ( topic1 => "You need more help", topic2 => "RTFM", );
    }
}
```

Remember that `our` merely legalizes a global variable name in a scope.  It doesn't create a new variable like `my` does.